# 1062, "Duplicate entry '3' for key 'user_id'"

Tags: django

Whenever I try to create a user through the admin panel I get this error. I've not idea why. But if I do it by `user = User.objects.create_user('aegon', 'g@ad.com', 'hehehe123')` it'll work fine. Any hints to what is causing this?

There's only one user in auth_user in my database.

[image]

error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '3' for key 'user_id'")
```

my models:

```
class transaction(models.Model):
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    holding = models.ForeignKey(holding, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "amount: " + str(self.amount) + " - ip : " + str(self.holding.name) + " - user: " + str(self.user.username)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ip = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ingameName = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='NotSet')      
    userprofit = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    user_transactions = models.ForeignKey(transaction, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

Comment: The reason is probably with post_save signal code. Can you comment it and check - does the error gone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Probably a duplicate signal:**

The source of the error is actually in the `UserProfile` model, not the `User` itself. Exception message states that `user_id` (which is a reference to a `User` model from `UserProfile`) gets duplicated, so either such record for `User` with `id = 3` already exists in the table, or `post_save` signal is fired twice.

From the Django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals):

> In some circumstances, the code connecting receivers to signals may
>   run multiple times. This can cause your receiver function to be
>   registered more than once, and thus called multiples times for a
>   single signal event.

The solution is:

```
# Change 'name_your signal' to desired unique signal name within your app
post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User, dispatch_uid="name_your signal")
```

That will give your signal unique id and prevent it from firing multiple times.

**If that does not help:**

Sometimes you have to explicitly set primary key for a `OneToOne` relation:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
```

That will override the default primary key behavior, and won't produce an exception.